# State diagram relationships

Tags: state, uml, diagram, state-diagram

Can you tell me please,what types of relationship are there present in state diagrams and how they are represented? There is a lot described about class diagrams, but relationships in state diagrams I can't find anywhere.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic relation is a `Transition` (p. 357 of UML 2.5)

> A Transition represents an arc between exactly one source Vertex and exactly one Target vertex (the source and targets may be the same Vertex). It may form part of a compound transition, which takes the StateMachine from one steady State configuration to another, representing the full response of the StateMachine to an occurrence of an Event that triggered it.

Of course you can have `Dependency` and sometimes `ObjectFlow`. Others depending on context. UML allows to place anything in any diagram. So you could put in classes with associations and any other stuff as well (if it makes sense to the reader).

Comment: Thank you. What book is it from?

Comment: See https://www.omg.org/about/omg-standards-introduction.htm (bottom right). It's no lecure for bed time or self teaching. Just the naked truth.